# In the final fight with Ganon, can you leave?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In the final fight with beast Ganon, when you are in Hyrule Field, can you just run away and leave? If yes, what happens to the boss fight? If no, what prevents you from leaving?

PS: I made the question title vague to prevent spoilers that there's a final fight with beast Ganon. Those who finished the game will probably know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this GameFAQs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75142776?page=1):

> The border's only invisible until you get close to it, but yeah, you can't really leave the area.

There is an invisible border the prevents you from leaving the area (makes sense to not be able to just leave a boss fight).  You can only see the border when you are near it.

Comment: To add, here is a video of the barrier https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpHdaNPKmE8&feature=youtu.be (and a glitch that you can go through)

Comment: There's also a force-field that pops up during the first stage fight, so no escape once you start the fight.